# 403 Forbidden when trying import or export Phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

i have install Apache 2, configserver and modsecurity with OWASP on my VPS

so i can access domain.com/phpmyadmin,

after login as root, i trying to import DB but returrn error:

You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/tbl_import.php on this server.

How to re-config them?i follow some tutorial but not success.

Note: I login as root (renamed as abc ) and that account have full priville as root

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user account which you use to connect to the database with has enough rights to perform creates, drops etc.

Comment: So does phpmyadmin use this account to connect to the database? Check tje rights of the account

Comment: i think there is not cause by privvileg

Answer (score 0):

Do the permissions on tbl_import.php allow you to run it?

The error message you're getting might be because of a lack of permissions.

Which user/group is apache2 running as? What are the permissions of tbl_import.php?

If you're having issues setting the permissions, see [this](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) Wikipedia page.

Comment: If you go to phpMyAdmin's folder and type 'ls -l', do the permissions on tbl_import.php allow it to be run?